# Is it ethical to use an abandoned bicycle in my parking garage?

Tags: commuter

I've recently moved to a new city and need a bicycle.
I noticed an unlocked bike covered in dirt with flat tires in my apartment's parking garage.  Would it be ethical to clean it up and use it for my commute?  I would leave it back  in the same place at the end of each day.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about ethics, not bicycles.

Comment: True, but I think this community would be a good resource to answer such a question.

Comment: Its also winter in the northern hemisphere, and many people ride (and it doesn't take that long to get a flat tire). The bike may not even be abandoned.

Comment: I'm in Malaysia so there's no winter...

Comment: Ethics 101 - if you need to ask it's not ethical.

Comment: The question, of course, is whether it's truly abandoned.  If it is then there's no ethical issue with using it, but there's no real way to know (especially for us in a different culture).  Suggestion:  Air up one of the tires and see how long it takes to go flat.  If you fill the tire to, say, 50 psi and it's still above 40 psi a week later then (if the tires are completely flat now) likely the bike's been sitting there for a year or so.  If the tire flattens faster it may only be a month or two, and the owner could be out of town or some such.

Comment: Always ask. Post a note near the elevators/staircase asking if you can use the bike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get your logic.  So you would share with the rightful owner?

Borrowing is stealing.

When is property abandoned is a legal question.

I am not an attorney and don't take this a legal advice but to me a unlocked bike in public or semi public place for more than 30 days is abandoned.

I seriously doubt you can just air it up and ride it.  On an economical level if you have to put new tires on it you are not getting a good return.  The rightful owner or a person with even less ethics than you will take it.

Look for a used cheap bike. But then you don't know if you are buying a stolen bik

Comment: >Property is theft. >People spouting moral platitudes are universally cretinous.

Comment: Better hope that "property is theft" doesn't come across as a moral platitude.  ;-)

Comment: You're right, I need to determine property laws and if it's truly abandoned.  I'll contact the condo management to see how they deal with this issue.